# Android 9 having problems while uploading Images using Retrofit multipart?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

I am using Retrofot2.x for the multipart purpose to upload images and as well as username, password with that but it's not working in pie OS
My Code is working fine for marshmallow and Nougat devices but not working with pie it just shows this in logcat of my project

```java
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=57fed95e-fdc8-4835-bfaf-a1198fa92363
Content-Length: 834
```

I didn't get how to resolve this I tried a lot of solutions. But not resolve

Comment: Post your entire error

Comment: @Saurabh Throat I got only those above two lines when I hit the API to upload the image but same works in nougat